# dplyr mutate to create a variable containing the first instance of the minimum value of other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a column that contains the minimum value of another column, and NAs for the rest. This attempt using `dplyr`'s `mutate()` and `case_when()` is close enough (see reprex below). But I want to keep the just the first instance of it. So, in case of several rows have the same minimum value, I want to keep in my new var only the first that appears in the data (or the last one). So, in the example below, `min_mpg` should have the value 10.4 only in the Cadillac Fleetwood row.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
mtcars |> 
  mutate(min_mpg = case_when(
    mpg == min(mpg) ~ mpg,
    .default = NA
  ))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb min_mpg
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      NA
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      NA
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      NA
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      NA
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      NA
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      NA
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4      NA
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2      NA
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2      NA
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4      NA
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4      NA
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3      NA
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3      NA
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3      NA
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4    10.4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4    10.4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4      NA
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1      NA
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2      NA
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1      NA
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1      NA
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2      NA
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2      NA
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4      NA
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2      NA
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1      NA
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2      NA
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2      NA
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4      NA
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6      NA
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8      NA
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So, it's somewhat similar of what you can achieve with `slice_min()`, but using `with_ties = FALSE`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
mtcars |> 
  slice_min(order_by = mpg)
#>                      mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
mtcars |> 
  slice_min(order_by = mpg ,with_ties = FALSE)
#>                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.25 17.98  0  0    3    4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

How can I achieve that?  (well, I can use this `slice_min()` approach and `left_join()` my way to achieve the desired result. But I am pretty sure there must be a simpler / more elegant and succinct way. I just can't find it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not pretty, but you could do

```
mtcars |> 
  mutate(min_mpg = case_when(
    cumsum(mpg == min(mpg))==1 ~ mpg,
    .default = NA
  ))
```

The `cumsum` will count the number of times a value is equal to the min, and here you just specifically ask for the first time the min appears

Comment: clever!, thx. I just got also another solution using `row_number()`, so I leave it here as well 
`mtcars |> 
  mutate(min_mpg = case_when(
    row_number(mpg) == 1 ~ mpg,
    .default = NA
  ))`